# Counting and storing distinct elements and their counts from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of object and I want to count the number of distinct elements and counts of those objects.

```
[ { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  }
]
```

I want to count the number of distinct names and store them in an object. I have tried it by 1# pushing all the names in an array,
2# then sorting them,
3# then calculating the number of distinct names and
4# finally pushing them to the object.
This process is too long. Is there a shorter way to do this. I am using Nodejs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great place to use the [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single
>   value.
>
> ...
>
> reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array, excluding holes in the array, receiving four arguments: the
>   initial value (or value from the previous callback call), the value of
>   the current element, the current index, and the array over which
>   iteration is occurring.

It would look something like this:

```
var arr = [ { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  }
]

var counts = arr.reduce(function(counts, item) {
    counts[item.name] = (counts[item.name] || 0) + 1;
    return counts;
}, {});
```

`counts` is then:

```
{ Suman: 2, Namus: 2 }
```

---

Asked in the comments:

> what if i want the count as well as name in an array of object like
>   `[{name: 'Suman', count:'2'}, {name:'Namus', count:'2'}]`

If you already have `counts` from the `reduce` call above, then you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) its keys to the format you want:

```
var countsArray = Object.keys(counts).map(function(name) {
    return {name: name, count: counts[name]};
});
```

`countsArray` is then:

```
[ { name: 'Suman', count: 2 },
  { name: 'Namus', count: 2 } ]
```

Comment: what if i want the count as well as name in an array of object like 
[{name: 'Suman', count:2}, {name:'Namus', count:2}]

Comment: Thanks mate, I had never understood mapping clearly. You just opened my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You will create a new object, where the key is the name and the value the count:

```
var youArr = [ 
  { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Suman',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  },
  { name: 'Namus',
    game: '5A'
  }
];

var count = {}
for(var i=0; i < youArr.length; i++){
    count[youArr[i].name] = count[youArr[i].name] || 0;
    count[youArr[i].name]++;
}

alert(count['Namus']); // 2
```